# Show that the number of occurrences of the symbol $\land$ in a formula $\phi$ is less than or equal to the number of left brackets ( in the forumla.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, propositional-calculus

> Use mathematical induction on the length of a formula to show that the number of occurrences of the symbol $\land$ in a formula $\phi$ is less than or equal to the number of left brackets ( in the forumla. (I will abbreviate this as 'the condition' from now on.) The length of a formula is the
>   number of occurrences of connectives in it.

Could anyone please check if my proof below is correct please? Thank you so much!

Base case: Let's say the length of $\phi$ is $0$, so it's just a propositional variable. That means there is no $\land$ or any other connective, so there is no ( either. Condition fulfilled.

Induction hypothesis: Assume that for $\phi$ with a length of  $\le n$, the number of $\land$ it has is less than/equal to the number of left brackets.

Induction step: I will now show that for $\phi$ with a length of $\le n+1$ this condition still holds. According to rule ii) below, $\phi$ can only be in 1 of 5 forms. Let's prove them case by case. Assume that $\phi$ has a length of $n+1$.

$\phi=\lnot\theta$: The connective $\lnot$ does not add either $\land$ or left bracket to the formula. As for $\theta$, it has a length of $\le n$, so by the induction hypothesis $\theta$ fulfills the condition.

$\phi=(\theta\land\psi)$: Both $\theta$ and $\psi$ have a length of $\le n$, so by the induction hypothesis they both fulfill the condition. There is just one outer left bracket - same amount as the $\land$. Thus $\phi$ fulfills the condition.

For $\phi=(\theta\lor\psi)$, $\phi=(\theta\to\psi)$, and $\phi=(\theta\iff\psi)$, the proof is essentially the same as my proof for $\phi=(\theta\land\psi)$.

Thus all possible cases of $\phi$ having a length of $n+1$ fulfills the condition.

The rules are as follows:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Correct; basically there are only three cases: 1) $\lnot$: no new left parentheses and  no new $\land$; 2) $\land$: one more $\land$ and one more left p; 3) all other binary connectives: no new $\land$ and one more left p.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that the case with other connectives (except negation) is slightly different from the case of conjunction till you mentioned it; I should have been more careful.

Comment: Sorry one more question: had the symbol concerned been changed to $\lnot$, the condition will no longer hold...right? Because for the induction step where the length of $\phi$=$n+1$, if $\phi=\lnot\theta$, then even though for $\theta$ by the induction hypothesis the condition is fulfilled, the outer $\lnot$ will fail the condition?

Comment: Correct. According to the syntactical rules above, the negation sign is written $\lnot \theta$ and not $(\lnot \theta)$. Thus, we may have the formula $\lnot \lnot \lnot \lnot (p \land q)$ where the number of occurences of $\lnot$ is $4$ and the number of left brackets is $1$.